# Extract contents of Zip file downloaded using a HTTP GET request

Tags: java, get, zip, unzip

I have to download a Zip file, from rest call and extract its contents (some PDF files and a PNG file).

I'm using Java Spring.

How can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Spring's RestTemplate to download the file

```
RestTemplate templ = new RestTemplate();
byte[] downloadedBytes = templ.getForObject(url, byte[].class);
```

Extract the contents with standard java or a third party library.

Example utility, adapted from here: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/programmatically-extract-a-zip-file-using-java

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class ZipHelper {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public static void unzip(byte[] data, String dirName) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(dirName);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();

        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = dirName + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
            } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }

    private static void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();
    }
}
```

Then you use this utility like so:

```
ZipHelper.unzip(downloadedBytes, "/path/to/directory");
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to decode response? r thinks the library used?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "r thinks" ?

Comment: Sorry, 'or',    somthing like that?:                                                                      Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();
   decompressor.setInput(file);
   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(file.length);
   byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
   while (!decompressor.finished()) {
      int count = decompressor.inflate(buf);
      bos.write(buf, 0, count);
   }
   bos.close();
      byte[] decompressedData = bos.toByteArray();

Comment: I think ZipInputStream is a more general purpose algorithm than Inflator (zlib). Do you want to extract the zip file into a directory on disk?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a complete utility for unzip.

Comment: Thanks, I have to extract zip into folder.

Comment: Thanks man:), everythigs works correctly. I can't vote  your answer I can  because I don't have the privileges, but I am very grateful:). have a good day :)).

Comment: Just accept the answer, no need to vote. (click on the tick next to my answer) Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between **unzip** and **extract**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky no difference. When we say extract we mean unzip.

Answer (score 0):

The requesdt body should be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/push/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String pushTransactions(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody byte[] str) throws MessagingException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
```

and in controller, you can do this:

```
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(str));
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len;
        while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        gis.close();
        out.close();
```

Comment: @RequestBody byte[] srt throws an exception : The annotation is disallowed for this location.

Comment: @FrancescoPerfetti check my sample again. I have edited